# Is the semicolon (;) notation used to indicate operations are performed concurrently in backpropagation algorithm by Bengio?

Tags: notation, backpropagation

I am trying to understand the backpropagation algorithm in a multi-layer perceptron environment.

> Algorithm 6.4 Backward computation for the deep neural network of
> algorithm 6.3, which uses, in addition to the input $\boldsymbol{x}$,
> a target $\boldsymbol{y}$. This computation yields the gradients on
> the activations $\boldsymbol{a}^{(k)}$ for each layer $k$, starting
> from the output layer and going backwards to the first hidden layer.
> From these gradients, which can be interpreted as an indication of how
> each layer's output should change to reduce error, one can obtain the
> gradient on the parameters of each layer. The gradients on weights and
> biases can be immediately used as part of a stochastic gradient update
> (performing the update right after the gradients have been computed)
> or used with other gradient-based optimization methods. After the
> forward computation, compute the gradient on the output layer:
>
> ${g} \leftarrow \nabla_{\hat{y}} J=\nabla_{\hat{y}} L(\hat{y},
> > y)1$
>  `for`$k$ `from` $k=l, l-1, ...$
> `to`$1$
>    
>  Convert the gradient on the layer's output into a
> gradient on the prenonlinearity activation (element-wise
> multiplication if $f$ is element-wise): 
>  
>   ${g} \leftarrow
> > \nabla_{{a}^{(k)}} J={g} \odot f^{\prime}\left({a}^{(k)}\right)$
>    Compute
> gradients on weights and biases (including the regularization term,
> where needed):
>     
> $\nabla_{{b}^{(k)}} J={g}+\lambda
> > \nabla_{{b}^{(k)}}\Omega(\theta)$
>   
>  $\nabla_{{W}^{(k)}} J={g} ;{h}^{(k-1)
> > \top}+\lambda \nabla_{{W}^{(k)}}$`<--- HERE`
>    
>  Propagate the gradients w.r.t. the next
> lower-level hidden layer's activations:
>   
>   ${g} \leftarrow
> > \nabla_{{h}^{(k-1)}} J={W}^{(k) \top};{g}$ `<--- HERE`
>
> Bengio and al., *Deep Learning*

I struggle to understand what `";"` means in the algorithm. Is the semicolon (;) notation used to indicate that operations are performed concurrently (element-wise)like performing an element-by-element multiplication between the gradient g and the former activation layer h(k-1)? But shouldn't it be $\odot$?

I wonder if Bengi and al. aren't complicating the algorithm ...
I am a slow learner in mathematics, so don't hesitate to use easy concepts ;)